# Why does 'cvs update' not update any files?

Tags: cvs

I think our CVS is not set up correctly, but I am finding that doing `cvs update foldername` does not cause *any* of the files in it to be updated.

What is the proper way to do an update if update doesn't work?

CVS updates are supposed to be recursive. Why should I have to `cd` into the directory?

Comment: Try `cvs -t update -d`. If that doesn't work, post the output.

Comment: You should change into foldername and simply do `cvs update` there.

Comment: cvs update is supposed to be recursive. Why should I have to cd into the directory?